# CSS: position:absolute div inside position:relative div -- what am i doing wrong?

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

after reading this article:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

i am trying to achieve vertically stacked divs each containing 2 child divs positioned to the far left and right of each parent div. i found the same concept here:

[Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

but I can't figure out why mine isn't working.The in-progress file can be viewed here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10388895/newPeterSalvatoDotCom/index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please include the relevent code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this would be to give the `projectDivs` a height. They currently collapse to `0`. Add the following to your stylesheet and see what happens:

```
.projectDivs{height:600px}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. I didn't realize the divs would collapse when the contents were absolutely positioned... but it makes sense since they are taken out of the document flow... 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting these rules to the `.projectDivs` class get what you want done.  Let me know if they don't.

```
.projectDivs {position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

i set the margins individually because you have a margin bottom set already.

Comment: got it sorted, but thanks for taking the minute to take a look.