# 'position: static;' vs 'position: relative;' when child element is absolutely positioned

Tags: css, position, css-position

I am struggling to understand why I need to add `position: relative;` for a container element when its child element is positioned absolutely (i.e. `position: absolute;`). Let me explain by example.

**Sample HTML Code:**

```
<ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li id="parent">
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <div id="child">...</div>
   </li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Consider that the code represents a horizontal menu. Which appears somewhat like this:

[image: screenshot]

**The problem** is when the value of the `position` property of `#parent` is default (i.e. `position: static;`), its width increases with the width of the `#child` even though the child element is positioned absolutely, which shouldn't be happening as `#child` is now out of the flow due to `position: absolute;`.

Everything falls in place, when I use `position: relative;` on `#parent` i.e. its width stays the same, no matter what the size of the `#child`.

What am I missing here? Why do I need to use `position: relative;` for something that (I presume) should be the default behavior?

**UPDATE:** I've created a fiddle to better explain my point. [Please take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/bdtt3/).

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

- In the preview of the fiddle, click on the "Channels" menu, which should slide out its hidden menu-item.
- Now, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> key in your browser (Chrome, Safari, or Firefox with Firebug installed), use the inspect tool to inspect the "Channels" menu.

  That should immediately point you to the relevant HTML code in the "Elements" tab of the now open Dev Tools or Firebug pane.

  Look for the first instance of `<li class="float-left top-menu">` inside `<ul id="top-navbar">` and hover your mouse over that line. It should show you something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Why is the blue indicator box (i.e. the menu) that big when it should be the size of the red border? Get the idea of what I am saying now?

Now, apply `position: relative;` on the `li` (i.e. `li.float-left.top-menu { position: relative; }` and see the difference for yourself.)

Comment: Please provide CSS and browser used as well, from html example your warping block div into inline a - this can have unpredictable results, i would try to adding display:block to a. As is i cant seem to repeat your issue.

Comment: @drk Was working on it as soon as I realized the explanation wasn't enough. Please check my updated question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I feel stupid now. I was using `min-width` on the child element, and since the width is pretty much defined, the menu's (i.e. parent's) width expanded as well. Removing `min-width` cleared all doubts.

And a **MUST READ: [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)** (also [this comment](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/#comment-23750) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487329)).

Comment: Also to note you example on jsfiddle didnt have position for submenu container, adding following css reduced the size of first li to expected size :

    #channels-menu-item-container{
        position:absolute;       
    }

Comment: @drk I think you are mistaken. I used `position:absolute;` on the class `.collapse` which targets the same element as `#channels-menu-item-container`, or am I missing something?

Comment: aah, it get removed when the menu is expanded - which was the state i did the testing, expanding the main menu after opening sub may be your goal that i didnt factor in.

Comment: @drk Looks like something's wrong with JS Fiddle (or the bootstrap library that it loads), it's fine on the live site; the class shouldn't get removed. Anyway, thanks for letting me know. :) **EDIT:** The issue is caused by the old bootstrap library that JS fiddle loads. Everything should be fine with the latest version of bootstrap. Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdtt3/1/

Answer (score 3):

`position:relative` creates a new containing box from which any absolutely positioned child elements will set their top/left relative to.

`position: static` will not create a containing box and any child elements that are absolutely positioned will start walking up the DOM tree to find a containing box until it hits the body and use the ancestor it finds for the top/left.

**Edit:** Sorry I misread your question. I cannot seem to reproduce your description of the problem (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TfJz/)). Can you please post the code a minimal test case of your problem.

Comment: but that doesn't answer the OP's question: why does the parent expand if the child is removed from the flow of the document?

Comment: JaredMcAteer and @Matanya Please see my updated question. I have added a fiddle and steps to reproduce the problem. Thanks!