# CSS missing from website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using bootstrap and HTMl boilerplate to start up a site. I'm having an issue over writing the brand class from bootstrap. In main.css I added a .navbar .brand class and I'm attempting to change float to top. When I load my web page in the browser my .navbar .brand in main.css is blank (according to firebug). I can edit bootstraps float value to top while using firebug, but I can't seem to override using my own style sheet.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">        
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="">Alex</a>
```

in bootstrap.css

```
.navbar .brand {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 17px 20px 17px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #013435;
}
```

in main.css

```
.navbar .brand {
  float: top;
}
```

and then in firebug when I look at the element

```
.navbar .brand {        main.css (line 27)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `float:top` is not a valid rule. So the browser recognises the selector but not the rule you have applied.

These are the possible values for `float`:

- `float: left`
- `float: right`
- `float: none`
- `float: inherit`

Useful article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float

Comment: Bah, that's annoying. I tried the value in firebug first and it seemed to move my text vertically. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In Firebug you might have unset the float. Try using `float: none;`.

Answer (score 1):

`float` can't be `top`. Floats are only used to align items horizontally.

Maybe the `position:relative` + `position:absolute` technique will do for you: [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)