# Positioning an image within an another?

Tags: html, css, web

I have an iphone-template and I have a screen image. I want the screen image to position itself inside the iphone template. I tried using the position property in CSS but the screen image goes to the top of the entire web-page instead of the div.

```html
<div class="span4" id="iphone-white">
    <img class="iphone-white-img" src="img/iphone-wht-front.png" alt="" />
    <div id="iphoneInside">
        <img class="On imgSize" id="screen1" src="img/blue.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.iphone-white-img {
    max-height: 720px;
    max-width: 337px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.imgSize
{
    max-height: 620px;
    max-width: 287px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your #iphone-white div needs to be position:relative. The .iphone-white-img element is not a parent of .imgSize, which is why it isn't containing the absolute-positioned element.

Comment: yes, that did it, I have another question, what CSS can I use to perfectly place the screen image inside the template?

Comment: I would use the `top:` and `left:` CSS properties to adjust the screen image until it is positioned where you want it. Something like `.imgSize { top: 20px; left: 10px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the z-index attribute if you want an image to overlap another image. The one you want to be on top should have the higher z-index. So, if in your case imgSize is insinde the iphone, add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to its style and then adjust the positioning. And also, you don't need that inner div.

Comment: good point, but the screen image is still on the top of the web page, how do I  bring it down so that I can position it on top of the template in that particular div?

Comment: Well, first of all I think you should change both positionings to absolute, so that resizing window doesn't mess it up. And then just fiddle with left-top-bottom-right attributes. For example `left: 50px;` will move your element 50 px to the left and so on until you find the correct setting

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent (.iphoneInside) has position: relative

From [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)