# How can I overlap divs inside of a parent div when parent uses auto height?

Tags: html, css, z-index, positioning

I have two divs that I would like to place one on top of the other, so I can create a tab system in an applet I am making. These two divs reside within a parent div, that uses auto height because I do not know the exact height of the other two divs (both children will be of same height). I can position the two divs one on top of the other with absolute positioning when the parent uses relative positioning, but the auto height doesn't respond (most likely because of absolute positioned children) creating a border line of an empty div instead of a wrapper with elements inside.

See problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/h5bjt69s/

```
<div id = "parent">
    <div id = "redDiv"></div>
    <div class = "clearfix"></div>
    <div id = "blueDiv"></div>
</div>
```

I tried modeling a solution from this, but I believe the auto height throws things off.
[Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

How can I wrap the two divs with the parent div and still maintain the overlaying of the two children?

Comment: Please post your code. Don't post a Fiddle link as code.

Comment: what actually are you trying to obtain??

Comment: Are your trying this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/h5bjt69s/1/)

Comment: @Benjamin Is the z-index the only thing you changed?

Comment: @user3735633 Is this is what are you trying

Comment: I believe it is. Thank you. @Benjamin The purpose was to have two plots on top of each other, eventually I will make a tab system that switches the visibility/z-index to display each one on a tab click.

Comment: Below check my answer what have I changed

Comment: @user3735633 Good luck with your website.

Comment: Thank you all. Both solutions work (I tested them both on site). @Salman A solution is a little simpler because z-index is not needed on both children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

> both children will be of same height

Actually solves your problem:

- Position one div using `position: static`; it will determine the height of the parent
- Position the other div(s) using `position: absolute` (it will appear on top)

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/h5bjt69s/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the changes

```
#blueDiv {   
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;/*changed*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:2;/*added*/
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/h5bjt69s/3/)

Another Style

```
#blueDiv {   
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    /*position: relative;removed*/
    opacity:0.7;
}

#redDiv {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;/*added*/
}
```

**[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/h5bjt69s/7/)**