# css style for div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display the button in div tag on right side.I use the code which I used to display the div content on right side.Now I have a problem that my div tag display on left side.
I want to display login div tag on right side.
I created a layout.I want to display login div tag where I marked as red and named it btn div.I marked current display of div tag in blue color.
[image]

CSS

```
.login {
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 0px 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    width:40%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login">//btn</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mount/q4gxv7y2/

Comment: try on the header `position: relative` and the div login/btn `position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: No needs to make hard stats: position: relative/ position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; is what you have to do:)

Comment: You need to try more CSS option before you ask. Study here http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an absolute position for your login div. For that, you also have to set the header position as relative, in order to make position the login div relatively to it.

[Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent?rq=1)

```css
.header{
   position:relative;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:300px
}
.login{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 0px 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    width:40%;
  
  position:absolute; 
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header"> 
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="login">
          //btn 
      </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems like you beat me to it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
}

. login  {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"> 
    <div class="ribbon">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="login">
    //btn 
    </div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    outline:1px solid green;
    position:relative;   
}
.login{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 0px 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    outline:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uj0grnph/)

**Side note:** Keep in mind that `class` is only used for objects placed more than once on a page. If an object is only placed once on the page, in your case for example: `header`, `logo`, then you should use `id` instead of `class`. Biggest reason for this is because `id`'s have a higher *specificity score* compared to classes. So you can give styles to all objects more controlled.

Comment: I have two buttons now both are displayed in same place.

Comment: Then for one button change: `bottom:0` to `bottom:40` or whatever amount of pixels fits best.

Comment: please view my jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="header"> 
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login">
         <input type='button' value='right click' class='right-button'>
    </div>   
</div>
```

css:

```
.login{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 0px 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px green solid;
}
.right-button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqn8sbno/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

CSS

```
.login {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    width:40%;
}
.ribbon{
    float:left;
}
.logo{
    float:left;
}
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:auto; // or specify the max height of content
    outline:none
    position:relative;   
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login">//btn</div>
</div>
```