# Place an absolute positioned element relative to its direct parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Usually, an absolutely positioned element (`position:absolute`) is placed relatively to its closest positioned ancestor.

Now, I want to place that element relatively to its direct parent.

What I could obviously do, is:

- taking the parent
- checking whether it is already positioned
- if not, adding position: relative to it
- proceeding in positioning the element

I am pretty sure there must be a simpler solution, any ideas?

Comment: No, you have to do that

Comment: well, you have the answer ... why do you think you can found easier ?

Comment: maybe an easier solution is to simple set the parent to relative without testing so you have only one instruction

Comment: It doesn't get any easier than: <div style="position: relative"><div style="position: absolute"></div></div>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are no easier solutions than make parent positioned

```
#parent {
   position: relative;
}
```

There are now other solutions (at least I can't found):

[Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

talkie talkie how it can be: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/position-an-element-relatively-to-another-element-from-anywhere-in-the-dom/968

All the same:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/advanced-positioning/