# How to have dynamic overlays over images in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

[image]

How to have an image in angular 2 like the one above, taken from facebook marketplace. The one I need is the black on, bottom-left.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper div around the image that has a `position` set to `relative`, and then create the overlay as a child div, with `position` set to `absolute`.

That will position it relative to the container

Here is an example:

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 500px;
}

.overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://greenwoodhypno.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/test-image.png" />

  <div class="overlay">
     $75
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is already an array of answers (over 9000) about [positioning div inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=position+div+inside+div). Should have marked as duplicate.