# CSS Absolute position on the right covers other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I have an div element that has `position: absolute;`. I want it to always be on the right edge and not cover other elements.

Here is my HTML:

```css
.color2 {
  background-color: #ff0078 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.colorW {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px #d4d4d4 dotted;
}

.condition-input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  width: 180px;
  height: 19px;
  background-color: #fff200;
  color: black;
}

.condition-button-group {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="badge color2">Height</span>
  <span class="badge colorW">==</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control condition-input" />
  <div class="d-inline condition-button-group">Text</div>
</div>
```

But on the page I see the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btTeZ.png). I don't want the "Text" to cover the left on the input, there should be an indentation. How to fix it?

Comment: perhaps you shouldn't use "position: absolute" for that div. check usages of "float: right" and try removing "position: absolute.". check this webpage if you are not familiar with float usage: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/float.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use absolute, your parent div needs to be positioned relative so that the absolutely positioned element is absolute within the parent and not the DOM as a whole (or other ancestors set to relative).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="badge color2">Height</span>
    <span class="badge colorW">==</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control condition-input"/>
    <div class="d-inline condition-button-group">Text</div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.condition-button-group {
   right:0;
   top:0;
}
```

Check out this link: [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

You may need to play with the style a bit to position it exactly where you want, but this is the route to take to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can add padding-right: 70px; to the parent div which is equal to the .condition-button-group class.

Updated code should looks like as below.

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="badge color2">Height</span>
    <span class="badge colorW">==</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control condition-input"/>
    <div class="d-inline condition-button-group">Text</div>
</div>

.parent{
    position:relative;
    padding-right:70px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

if you create any plunker that should be great.

Comment: This is good, no need for the padding as OP could position .condition-button-group absolutely in the parent when the parent is set to position:relative... so right:70px on .condition-button-group would do the same but making use of the positioning