# CSS position relative top 50% of div doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I have problem with positioning:

[image]

I cannot set exactly `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` on both photo and text because it isn't 50%. I try by hand set that 50% which is more like 46%.

When I change size of window text moves. I don't know what to Do and I am looking for answer for 2 hours

```css
.photo-box {
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, rgba(251, 10, 237, 0.84), rgba(0, 186, 255, 0.91) 50%, rgba(15, 226, 98, 1));
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f0eeee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.tytul {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  left: 45.3%;
}

.zdj-pierw img {
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-box" style="">

  <div class="tytul">Strona WWW </div>
  <div class="zdj-pierw">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random" width="200" height="200" />

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but Idk why it wont post without block of code

Comment: But you might find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: Could you help me Pete?

Comment: Read the big red error message when you remove the code block (the one that forced you to add it)

Comment: Okey . So what I have to change in code??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `flex` properties on the parent, not just on the item you want to place.

I've also changed your `border-radius` to `50%`, as this is a perfect round, no matter what the size of the image.

```css
.photo-box {
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, rgba(251, 10, 237, 0.84), rgba(0, 186, 255, 0.91) 50%, rgba(15, 226, 98, 1));
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  color: #f0eeee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tytul {
  position: absolute;
}

.zdj-pierw img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-box" style="">
  <div class="tytul">Strona WWW </div>
  <div class="zdj-pierw">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much