# Why is position:relative needed in order to position its children?

Tags: css

I'm looking at this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp. I thought that position:relative was used to position the element relative to its normal position.

Why is it needed in order to position its children? Isn't position:absolute on children enough?

Comment: The usage in that tutorial is more for the `absolute`ly positioned child. When you position something absolutely, it's relative to the closest `relative` or `absolute` parent. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent

Comment: I guess I missed that part about `absolute`. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an element "A" with `position:absolute`, the element "A" will be positioned based on the `body`. It will not have relation to its parent elements. But if the element "A" have a parent "B" with `position: relative`, the position of "A" will be related on this parent "B".

Comment: So position:relative has effect on how its children with position:absolute are positioned?

Comment: yes, it has effect on children with position: absolute.