# CSS position:relative required despite not using offset

Tags: css, css-position, pseudo-element

So, consider a "required" box that should be put above an `<input>` element using CSS pseudo-elements.

```
        <div>
          <label for="fname">First name: </label>
          <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" required>
          <span></span>
        </div>
```

This 'required' box will appear above the input box using `span::after`. We can set `position:absolute` on the `after` child and apply the offsets like its usually done.

However, this works only if the span element is set to `position:relative`. This doesn't make sense, because we are not applying offset to the span, only to it's child. But if we let span have its positioning in normal flow, this example won't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you give element position absolute the element is positioned absolutely to its first positioned parent. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487329/12237848) for better understand