# What is the way of the position CSS property affect its children?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the position of `PaginationBar-Wrapper` and `WriteButton-Wrapper` (Both are children of `Wrapper`) relative to the parent but don't affect each other. After read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent) in StackOverflow, I understand that `position: absolute` could be the answer for me.

According to the MDN, the position is property to set the position of itself, however, I find case that parent's position property affect children.

In the first case, It works perfectly for me.

```css
.Wrapper {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.PaginationBar-Wrapper {
    position: static;
}

.WriteButton-Wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

In the second case, it affects the children's height

```css
.Wrapper {
    position: static;
    flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.PaginationBar {
    position: static;
}

.WriteButton {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

What's the difference between these two cases? What is the way of the position property affect its children?

Here is HTML structure of these code.

```html
 <div className="Wrapper">
    <div className="PaginationBar-Wrapper">
      <PaginationBar />
    </div>
    <div className="WriteButton-Wrapper">
      <button className="write-button">작성하기</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please add the HTML code belonging to that CSS aswell!

Comment: @tacoshy I added HTML code.