# How to keep svg icon into the div instead of inside the main

Tags: html, css, svg, position

I have a problem with HTML/CSS. I'm trying to finish a challenge but i can't keep SVGs images in my div.

I will post screenshots of the attempted result then what i got.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq1WR.jpg)

And here my code : `

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
header {
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}
header h1 {
    font-weight: 200;
}
header strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
main {
    height: 80vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.card {
    position: static;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 9px;
    box-shadow: 8px 1px 20px grey;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.card:nth-child(1) {
    border-top: 5px solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
    border-top: 5px solid hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
} 
.card:nth-child(3){
    border-top: 5px solid hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
} 
.card:nth-child(4) {
    border-top: 5px solid hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
    grid-column: 2;
}
.card svg {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 10%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:360px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
    }
    main {
        height: auto;
        display: block;
    }
    .card {
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,600;1,200;1,400;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Four card feature section</title>
  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>
      Reliable, efficient delivery<br/>
      <strong>Powered by Technology</strong>
    </h1>
      Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points 
      to ensure that your project is successful
  </header>

  <main>
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Supervisor</h2>
        Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64"><g fill="none"><path fill="#676E74" d="M56.842 7.158c-9.526-9.563-24.902-9.525-34.428 0-8.025 8.026-9.45 20.44-3.525 30.003l-2.513 2.55-1.356 6.144 4.214 4.214 5.093-2.408 2.512-2.55a24.254 24.254 0 0030.003-3.525c9.563-9.526 9.525-24.902 0-34.428z"/><path fill="#474F54" d="M24.327 47.661l2.512-2.55a24.254 24.254 0 0030.003-3.525c9.563-9.526 9.525-24.902 0-34.428l-40.26 40.26 2.652 2.651 5.093-2.408z"/><path fill="#64E1DC" d="M54.213 9.787a20.56 20.56 0 00-14.585-6.041C28.236 3.746 19 12.98 19 24.372a20.564 20.564 0 006.041 14.586 20.564 20.564 0 0014.586 6.04c11.392 0 20.626-9.234 20.626-20.626a20.56 20.56 0 00-6.041-14.585z"/><path fill="#00C8C8" d="M60.254 24.372a20.56 20.56 0 00-6.041-14.585l-29.17 29.17A20.564 20.564 0 0039.627 45c11.392 0 20.626-9.235 20.626-20.627z"/><path fill="#EFEFF4" d="M56.239 23.41c-.184-.307-2.98-4.914-7.281-8.368-2.63-2.113-5.822-3.796-9.33-3.796-9.242 0-16.314 11.669-16.61 12.165l-.576.961.575.961c.184.309 2.98 4.916 7.28 8.37 2.631 2.112 5.823 3.795 9.33 3.795 9.243 0 16.315-11.668 16.612-12.165l.574-.96-.574-.962z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M56.239 25.333l.574-.96-.574-.962c-.184-.308-2.98-4.915-7.281-8.369l-18.66 18.66c2.63 2.113 5.822 3.796 9.33 3.796 9.242 0 16.314-11.668 16.61-12.165z"/><path fill="#64E1DC" d="M43.604 20.396a5.607 5.607 0 00-3.976-1.65 5.632 5.632 0 00-5.626 5.626c0 1.551.631 2.958 1.65 3.976a5.609 5.609 0 003.976 1.65 5.632 5.632 0 005.625-5.626c0-1.55-.63-2.957-1.649-3.976z"/><path fill="#00C8C8" d="M45.253 24.372c0-1.55-.63-2.957-1.649-3.976l-7.952 7.952a5.608 5.608 0 003.976 1.65 5.632 5.632 0 005.625-5.626z"/><path fill="#676E74" d="M40.954 23.046a1.876 1.876 0 10-1.326 3.2 1.876 1.876 0 001.326-3.2z"/><path fill="#474F54" d="M41.503 24.372c0-.517-.21-.986-.55-1.326l-2.65 2.652a1.876 1.876 0 003.2-1.326z"/><path fill="#575C60" d="M20.333 43.667l-3.957-3.957L0 56.049l3.975 3.976L7.951 64l16.376-16.339z"/><path fill="#333637" d="M24.327 47.661l-3.994-3.994L3.975 60.025 7.951 64z"/></g></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Team Builder</h2>
        Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64"><g fill="none"><path fill="#EFEFF4" d="M64 14.454v41.788H0V14.454l3.75-3.787h56.5z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M64 14.454v41.788H32V10.667h28.25z"/><path fill="#474F54" d="M0 0h64v15.515H0z"/><path fill="#32393F" d="M32 0h32v15.515H32z"/><g fill="#FF637B"><path d="M7.758 5.818h3.685v3.879H7.758zM15.128 5.818h3.685v3.879h-3.685zM22.497 5.818h3.685v3.879h-3.685z"/></g><path fill="#FF637B" d="M45.576 42.245V64H34.355v-3.71h-3.74V64H19.394V42.245l11.37-9.275h3.105z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M11.636 22.303h41.697v3.879H11.636z"/><path fill="#C9C9D3" d="M32 22.303h20.364v3.879H32z"/><path fill="#E63950" d="M45.576 42.245V64H33.939v-3.71H32V32.97h1.435z"/><path fill="#EFEFF4" d="M30.061 45.576h3.878v3.879h-3.878z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M32 45.576h1.939v3.879H32z"/><path fill="#676E74" d="M50.424 45.779l-2.452 2.706-15.487-13.526-15.488 13.526-2.452-2.706 17.94-15.718z"/><path fill="#474F54" d="M32 30.061l18.424 15.718-2.518 2.706L32 34.959z"/></g></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Calculator</h2>
        Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64"><g fill="none"><path fill="#474F54" d="M64 0v41.25l-3.75 3.875H3.75L0 41.25V0z"/><path fill="#32393F" d="M64 0v41.25l-3.75 3.875H32V0z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M22.625 50.875h18.75v11.25h-18.75z"/><path fill="#C9C9D3" d="M32 50.875h9.375v11.25H32z"/><path fill="#EFEFF4" d="M0 41.25h64v11.5H0z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M32 41.25h32v11.5H32z"/><path fill="#EFEFF4" d="M15.125 60.25h33.75V64h-33.75z"/><path fill="#DADAE5" d="M32 60.25h16.875V64H32z"/><path fill="#549EF2" d="M20.75 7.5c-7.236 0-13.125 5.889-13.125 13.125S13.514 33.75 20.75 33.75s13.125-5.889 13.125-13.125S27.986 7.5 20.75 7.5zm0 18.75a5.631 5.631 0 01-5.625-5.625A5.631 5.631 0 0120.75 15a5.631 5.631 0 015.625 5.625 5.631 5.631 0 01-5.625 5.625z"/><g fill="#377FD2"><path d="M45.125 7.5H56.5v3.75H45.125zM37.625 7.5h3.75v3.75h-3.75zM45.125 22.5H56.5v3.75H45.125zM37.625 22.5h3.75v3.75h-3.75zM37.625 15H56.5v3.75H37.625zM37.625 30H56.5v3.75H37.625z"/></g></g></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Karma</h2>
        Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64"><g fill="none"><path fill="#676E74" d="M26.375 52.625h11.25V64h-11.25z"/><path fill="#333637" d="M32 52.625h5.625V64H32z"/><path fill="#4C545A" d="M22.625 47h18.75v9.375h-18.75z"/><path fill="#52585C" d="M32 47h9.375v9.375H32z"/><path fill="#FFDA2D" d="M45.012 36.725c-2.325 1.913-3.637 4.612-3.637 7.425V47h-18.75v-2.85c0-2.85-1.238-5.512-3.3-7.125-5.062-3.938-7.95-9.862-7.95-16.275a20.585 20.585 0 017.613-16.013C22.7 1.737 27.238 0 32 0c1.462 0 2.962.15 4.425.45 8.1 1.688 14.475 8.45 15.9 16.663 1.275 7.5-1.425 14.85-7.313 19.612z"/><path fill="#FDBF00" d="M45.012 36.725c-2.325 1.913-3.637 4.612-3.637 7.425V47H32V0c1.462 0 2.962.15 4.425.45 8.1 1.688 14.475 8.45 15.9 16.663 1.275 7.5-1.425 14.85-7.313 19.612z"/><path fill="#676E74" d="M18.875 45.125h26.25v3.75h-26.25z"/><path fill="#FF9100" d="M39.956 10.143l2.651 2.651-3.979 3.978-2.651-2.651z"/><path fill="#FDBF00" d="M25.372 24.727l2.651 2.651-3.979 3.979-2.651-2.651zM30.125 28.25h3.75v5.625h-3.75z"/><path fill="#FF9100" d="M38.628 24.727l3.979 3.979-2.651 2.651-3.979-3.979zM39.5 18.875h5.625v3.75H39.5z"/><path fill="#FDBF00" d="M24.044 10.143l3.979 3.979-2.651 2.65-3.979-3.978zM18.875 18.875H24.5v3.75h-5.625zM30.125 7.625h3.75v5.625h-3.75z"/><g fill="#FFDA2D"><path d="M0 18.875h7.625v3.75H0zM6.585 14.81l-5.75-3.75 2.08-3.12 5.75 3.75zM2.915 33.56l-2.08-3.12 5.75-3.75 2.08 3.12z"/></g><path fill="#FDBF00" d="M56.375 18.875H64v3.75h-7.625zM61.085 33.56l-5.75-3.75 2.08-3.12 5.75 3.75zM57.415 14.81l-2.08-3.12 5.75-3.75 2.08 3.12z"/><path fill="#FF9100" d="M32 7.625h1.875v5.625H32zM32 28.25h1.875v5.625H32z"/><path fill="#333637" d="M32 45.125h13.125v3.75H32z"/><path fill="#FDBF00" d="M32 11.375c-5.175 0-9.375 4.2-9.375 9.375s4.2 9.375 9.375 9.375 9.375-4.2 9.375-9.375-4.2-9.375-9.375-9.375z"/><path fill="#FF9100" d="M32 30.125v-18.75c5.175 0 9.375 4.2 9.375 9.375s-4.2 9.375-9.375 9.375z"/><path fill="#FFDA2D" d="M30.125 18.875h3.75v3.75h-3.75z"/><path fill="#FDBF00" d="M32 18.875h1.875v3.75H32z"/></g></svg>
      </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Romain Desson</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

`
It looks like SVGs from card 2 and 4 are not recognized as a part of the card because they are placed at the position I want but as a child of the main and not the div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `.cards` should have a `position: relative;` right now they are `position: static;` meaning that the position of the svg isn't dependant of the cards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `position:static` to `position: relative` in `.card` class

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 9px;
    box-shadow: 8px 1px 20px grey;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```