# Make Select Option Display on top of Leaflet Map

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, leaflet, css-position

I'm trying to display a select tag on top of a leaflet map (using bootstrap).

I've tried amending the z-index in css but the select tag is still not visible.

What am I missing?

My HTML below:

```
<div id="mapid" class="container-fluid">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group form-row align-items-center">
         <select class="form-control" id="country-dropdown" name="country">
            <option value="-" id="select-country">Pick a Country...</option>
         </select>
        </div> 
     </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why is your `<form>` a child of the map?  You'd be better off making it a sibling

Comment: I need the map to cover the whole screen and the form to float on top, can I do this if it's a sibling?

Answer (score 1):

Make the `form` a sibling of the map, and use css to position it as you want.  If you want the map to be full screen, and the form to be laid out over it, use a common parent with `position: relative` to do that.  You can also use `pointer-events` in the css to allow interactivity with the map but still make your form elements usable:

```js
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

```css
.wrapper, #map, .form {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative
}

#map, .form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.form {
  z-index: 100000;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>


   
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="map"></div>
     <form class="form">
        <select class="form-control" id="country-dropdown" name="country">
          <option value="-" id="select-country">
            Pick a Country...
          </option>
         </select>
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text"> <input type="text">
<select class="form-control" id="country-dropdown" name="country">
          <option value="-" id="select-country">
            Pick a Country...
          </option>
         </select>
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text"> <input type="text"><select class="form-control" id="country-dropdown" name="country">
          <option value="-" id="select-country">
            Pick a Country...
          </option>
         </select>
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text"> <input type="text">
     </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Explanation of the CSS can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent