# How to overlay a div on a React-Leaflet map?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to create a card on top of my React-Leaflet map that shows some details of the map.
But my first issue is that, I can not overly my div(container of card) on top of map.
here is my code:

````
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13
    }
  }

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    return (
      <LeafletMap center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}
        id='mapDiv'
        >
        <div
          style={{
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
              top: 0,
                left: 0,
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                    zIndex: 10
          }}  
        />
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br/> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </LeafletMap>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample />, document.getElementById('container'))```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your div a sibling of the map container, not a child:

```js
<div 
  className="container"
  style={{
    position: 'relative'
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  }}
>
  <div
    style={{
      position: 'absolute'
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      zIndex: 10000
    }}  
  />
  <LeafletMap {...props}>
    {mapChildren}
  </LeafletMap>
</div>
```

You can see an example of this with vanilla leaflet here: [Make Select Option Display on top of Leaflet Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245949/12010984)

Comment: Thank you!!! Was facing the same issue. Now got resolved.

Comment: Except when this element needs to be inside of MapContainer in order to be able to access the context, then this becomes useless

Comment: @BCT there are other ways of accessing the map context outside of the child of a map.  This question did not specify that that was required.  Sounds like you have a separate question to ask.

Comment: I actually did have a question, but I managed to solve it by myself.