# How to overlay a div without messing with other div

Tags: css, css-position

I have a container div like this:-

```
<div class="container">
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to overlay the child div like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute)
But without touching the parent div css. How can I achieve this. I'll appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Comment: Use psiaudo element `.child:before`

Comment: You can use the same code from that link, the only difference is `position:relative` would go on `.container` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position absolute but relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent)

Comment: I'm asking what css should I apply to child container and I can't change the parent div css Or position.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from what you want to achieve but can try some of the below stuf :

- You can achieve that by using `top/bottom/left/right` property and `position: relative` to the `.child` according to need.
- You can achieve by using extra container and add `display: flex;width:100%` and using `justify-content` properties according to need .
- `float: left/right` can also be used according to need(but you will not able to position other than left, right and use `margin`)
- Simply by `top/bottom/left/right` `margin` can achieve the position .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  left: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```