# Text not aligned at the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css

In this example, the price text is aligned at the top of the container, I want it to be aligned at the bottom of it, like at the baseline

```css
.options {
    margin-top: auto;
    background: #ffaaff;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    line-height: 1;
}

.money {
  display: block;
}

.cart-price {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="price">
    <span class="cart-price">
      <span class="money">$49.50</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Decrease</button>
    <span >2</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent

Comment: you simply need to create a parent relative to container and then the child inside (i.e. ```cart-price```) to ```bottom:0;```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by adding `display: flex` and `align-items: end` to the `.price` div. Read more about flexbox (and `align-items`) [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.price {
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
}
```

```css
.options {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #ffaaff;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 1;
}

.money {
  display: block;
}

.cart-price {
  display: block;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="price">
    <span class="cart-price">
      <span class="money">$49.50</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Decrease</button>
    <span>2</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `price` class should have

```
align-self: flex-end;
```

which will align the div with price class vertically at the end of the flex.