# Flex not expanding to fill scrollable parent with absolute elements

Tags: css

Here's the code:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  outline: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.absolute-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(255 0 0 / 25%);
  outline: 1px solid rgb(255 0 0);
}

.static-child {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgb(0 128 0 / 25%);
  outline: 1px solid rgb(0 128 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="absolute-child">Absolute child. You'll have to scroll to see the full me.</div>
  <div class="static-child">Static child. If you scroll down, you'll see that I do not fill the entire flex, even though I'm set to flex: 1.</div>
</div>
```

I have a flex that has an absolutely positioned element and a statically positioned element. To make the absolute element not just overflow out of the box, I set the parent's position to relative and set overflow-y to scroll.

The problem is the static element. It works fine until you scroll. It seems that, **even if you set it's flex to 1, or height to 100%, the height simply becomes the size of the parent, rather than the entire scrollable area's worth of height, which would be what I want.**

It almost feels like that's a bug. If the reason for the scrolling of the element were static elements, this would work just fine, but what's causing the scroll here is the absolute element.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent?rq=2 answer your question?

Comment: @jahantaila Nope