# CSS: hover selector is not displaying image nested in a tag with display:block

Tags: css

I have a bunch if `<a>` tags that have unique ids associated with them and children elements that are `<img>`. I would like to have the images hidden (`display:none`) by default and have them become visible when you hover over the `<a>` tag to which they belong. However, currently when I try this behavior using the `#a-tag-id:hover` selector in my css, the image does not become visible in the event of hovering.

Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

here is a fiddle with the same behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/bobmrud0/1/

Here is the original haml/css:

```
#map
  %a#saddleback_point
    =image_tag('saddleback_college.png', width:'300px')
  %a#citrus_point
    =image_tag('citrus_college.png', width:'300px')
  %a#sonrise_point
    =image_tag('sonrise.png', width:'300px')
  %a#vegas_point
    =image_tag('vegas.png', width:'300px')
  %a#tennessee_point
    =image_tag('tennessee.png', width:'300px')
  %a#chestnut_point
    =image_tag('chestnut.png', width:'300px')
  %a#saint_point
    =image_tag('saint.png', width:'300px')
  %a#boston_point
    =image_tag('boston.png', width:'300px')
  %a#fisher_point
    =image_tag('fisher.png', width:'300px')

#citrus_point img{
   top:360px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:240px;
   position:absolute;
   display:none; //TODO This is broken!
}
#citrus_point:hover img{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: You know that `//` isn't valid CSS comment syntax right? And if you set something to display:none, how will hover get triggered if it's not being displayed?

Comment: @j08691 Regrettably, I didn't know. Now I do. I updated the Fiddle. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieved this on hover your element need to be the child of the element that is hovered.

The element whoes styles are needed to be changed must be the descendent of the hovered element to work

**Example**

See the example below

```css
 img{

   display:none; //TODO This is broken!
}
#my_a:hover img{
  display:block;
}
#my_a_withoutext{
   display:block;
   min-height:10px;
   min-width:10px;
   background:pink;
}
#my_a_withoutext:hover img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="unique_container">
    <a id="my_a">
        test
        <img src='http://0.tqn.com/y/altreligion/1/S/W/1/-/-/ouro-eliphas1947992_f248.jpg'/>
    </a>
   <a id="my_a_withoutext">
       
        <img src='http://0.tqn.com/y/altreligion/1/S/W/1/-/-/ouro-eliphas1947992_f248.jpg'/>
    </a>
    
</div>
```

In your case if no other elements are there in container and only the achor tag that you want to hover(that is child of the container) is visible than when you hover over it you are hovering parent. so you can generalize it for your specific condition this hack can work

```css
#my_a img{

   display:none; 
}
#my_a:hover img{
   display:block;
}

#test{
 
 
}
#test:hover{
  display:normal;
}
#unique_container:hover img{
    display:block;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="unique_container">
    <a id="my_a">
        <img src='http://0.tqn.com/y/altreligion/1/S/W/1/-/-/ouro-eliphas1947992_f248.jpg'/>
    </a>
    <a id="test">
        Hello Can you See Me?
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: so the `<a>` has to have some other content for the other hover to work? It can't be just an image? As in my original site the ideal behavior would involve a `<a>` tag without text...

Comment: I have tried selecting specifically for the `<img>` child of the `<a>` without having the text like you have there with "test" and it doesn't work.

Comment: no it can be an other image but it should have something visual so that user knows that he/she has to hover it

Comment: well the context is a map which is a background image, and when you hover over discrete points on the background image (which are visible to the user) then the absolutely positioned `<a>` tag child image corresponding to the background points would be displayed.

Comment: I don't know what HOTSPOTS are.

Comment: @Thalatta see it can work without text , but you need to make something to hover onto it

Comment: Yes but I was trying to follow the following advice via this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649184/image-hover-when-over-area-map see kristina childs advice on implementing hover effects which avoids all of the coords of the map.

Comment: @Thalatta i  have edited and placed another run script for your scenerio

Comment: Ok I get it now. Just do whatever you were doing but change your HTML using this implementation. So instead of images, use div id in normal/hover. Or from stackoverflow itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137517/how-to-position-absolute-inside-a-div