# How to overlay a fixed box over an img (div over div)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have been given positions in the form of an object for a box to be drawn over an image. I have tried to do this using a wrapper div but the box is positioned on the top right of the image and is not fixed to the image.

I want a bounding box to be drawn directly on the image given the position coordinates that resizes with the image. How can I edit the CSS to achieve what I'm looking for?

```
<div key={index} className="wrapper"> 
                <img src={`images/${item.Img_Name}`} className="App-images" alt="" loading="lazy"/>
                <div
                  style={{
                    position: "inherit",
                    top: `${item.Top}px`,
                    left: `${item.Left}px`,
                    width: `${item.Width}px`,
                    height: `${item.Height}px`,
                    border: "1px solid red",
                  }} className="Box">
                </div> 
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is the current CSS file

```
.Box {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.App-images {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems what you're trying to do here is position a div within the confines of another div. For this case, you would use `position: relative` and `position: absolute`, with `top` and `left` to change the location of the parent. For more details, visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365963/17199922). Below is an example in the limited code you copy pasted in from your question, with the HTML being the same:

```css
.Box {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute; /* the position */
  top: 10px; /* can also be sent to percents, vw, etc. places position in  parent*/
  left: 10px; /* can also be sent to percents, vw, etc. places position in  parent */
}

.App-images {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  position: relative; /* this is for the parent */
}
```

Here is an easier to understand example:

```css
div.main { /* parent */
  border: 2.5px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2.5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

div.apart { /* child */
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=main>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <div class=apart>10px top+left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the box absolute to the image instead of absolute to the page?

Comment: @coco In the example, the box is absolute to `div.main`. You cannot embed anything within the image. Although, you could use a div with the `background-image` set to the URL. Additionally, another solution could be to use the `bottom` and `right` css properties if you want an image caption. Example: https://replit.com/@aimedtuba/so-coco